Exception error after flutter procect copy
I'm new to flutter.
I'm trying to copy an existing flutter project for my next project.
I tried following, but I still receive an exception error. What are reason and how could I resolve this?

Copy an existing project. Select the project folder and copy and paste it to a new location.
Decide on a new project name. Please rename the copied project folder.
Open the pubspec.yaml file and change the name property to the new project name.
Change the package name. Updated the package name (e.g. com.example.newproject) on both Android and iOS.
For Android, edit the package attribute in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
For iOS, edit her PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.
Update dependencies -> found pubspec.yaml file are up to date and updated.
Clean the project. Run the flutter clean command in terminal to remove old build files.
Rebuild the project. Run flutter pub get to get the dependencies and rebuild the project.

Error message after running debug:
Exception has occurred. TestFailure (Expected: exactly one matching candidate   Actual: _TextWidgetFinder:<Found 0 widgets with text "0": []>    Which: means none were found but one was expected )


try to run main method that located in lib/main.dart, because it seems that you are running test

You are totally right. It went through. Thank you very much.

As i said in the comment, run main method that located in lib/main.dart, because it seems that you are running test.
